# Issue with fabrics 'TwitterCore' 'Digits' on Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, twitter-fabric

Im unable to install digits pod on Xcode 8. I need to use phone number login for the app. Any alternative approach. Im receiving

[!] Unable to find a specification for `TwitterCore (= 2.5.0)` depended upon by `Digits`

Ive tried installing TwitterCore
[!] Unable to find a specification for `TwitterCore`

Any help much appreciated

Comment: What's your pod file exactly?

Comment: pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Digits'